# How to be more efficient/faster with this MatrixExp-vector multiplication?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I am looking for expertise that helps to improve speed of the code below. First, a little bit of background:

There is some system of differential equations $\dot{\vec{m}}(t)=S(t)\vec{m}(t)$. In order to solve this without using `NDSolve/NDSolveValue` for this one can just proceed as $$\vec{m}(T)=\left(\prod\limits_{j=N}^1 e^{S(j\,dt)}\right) \cdot\vec{m}(0)$$
where $dt$ is length of one timestep and $N=T/dt$ the number thereof. Obviously, this method involves the matrix exponential of $S$ which can be time consuming, especially since $N$ should be on the order of $10^3$ for my purposes to achieve reasonable accuracy.

Let me define the system in Mathematica code (the important variable is `mat` which corresponds to $S(t)$ - the tiny rest is needed to construct a sample matrix that is almost of same dimension and "sparsity" as the ones I am actually dealing with)

```
ClearAll[init, listDiag, listOffDiag, valOffDiag, tmp, mat, col, squ];

col[mat_?MatrixQ] := Flatten[Transpose[mat]]; (* stack columns of a matrix *)

squ[list_?VectorQ] := Transpose[ArrayReshape[list, {Sqrt[Length@list], Sqrt[Length@list]}]]; (* transform stacked column form into square matrix again *)

(* preliminary definitions of initial condition and `tmp` that is needed to construct `mat` *)
init = ConstantArray[0, {36, 36}];
init[[8, 8]] = 1;

listOffDiag = {{13, 1}, {13, 7}, {14, 2}, {14, 8}, {15, 3}, {15, 9}, {16, 4}, {16, 10}, {17, 5}, {17, 11}, {18, 6}, {18, 12}, {19, 1}, {19, 7}, {20, 2}, {20, 8}, {21, 3}, {21, 9}, {22, 4}, {22,10}, {23, 5}, {23, 11}, {24, 6}, {24, 12}, {25, 1}, {25, 7}, {26,2}, {26, 8}, {27, 3}, {27, 9}, {28, 4}, {28, 10}, {29, 5}, {29, 11}, {30, 6}, {30, 12}};

listDiag = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}, {11, 11}, {13, 13}, {14, 14}, {15, 15}, {16,16}, {17, 17}, {18, 18}, {19, 19}, {20, 20}, {21, 21}, {22, 22}, {23, 23}, {24, 24}, {25, 25}, {26, 26}, {27, 27}, {28, 28}, {29, 29}, {30, 30}, {31, 31}, {33, 33}, {34, 34}, {35, 35}};

valOffDiag = t*RandomReal[{-5, 5}, Length@listOffDiag];
tmp = SparseArray[Join[Thread[Rule[listDiag, RandomReal[{-100, 100},Length@listDiag]]],Thread[Rule[Table[{30 + i, 30 + i}, {i, 1, 6}],ConstantArray[0, 6]]]]] + SparseArray[Join[Thread[Rule[listOffDiag,valOffDiag]], {{36, 36} -> 0}]] + Transpose@SparseArray[Join[Thread[Rule[listOffDiag, valOffDiag]],{{36, 36}->0}]];

mat = KroneckerProduct[tmp, IdentityMatrix[36]] + KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[36], Transpose@tmp];
```

Now here are my two approaches. Observing `AbsoluteTiming` of

```
MatrixExp[-I*SparseArray[ArrayRules[mat] /. t -> 3,Dimensions[mat]]].col[init]; // AbsoluteTiming
MatrixExp[-I*SparseArray[ArrayRules[mat] /. t -> 3, Dimensions[mat]],col[init]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

yields an order of magnitude improvement of the latter over the former (0.254 vs 0.027) on my machine. So instead of first computing the matrix product surrounded by the parentheses in the system of ODEs above, it should be faster to use `MatrixExp[matrix,vector]` sequentially.

```
evol1[mat_, initial_, ti_, tf_] := Module[
   {dt = (tf - ti)/10, res, d = Dimensions[mat][[1]]},
   res = Prepend[Table[MatrixExp[-I*SparseArray[ArrayRules[mat]/.t->i, Dimensions[mat]]], {i,ti, tf, dt}], col[initial]];
   Return[squ[Apply[Dot, Reverse[res]]]]];

evol2[mat_, initial_, ti_, tf_] := Module[
   {dt = (tf - ti)/10, res = col[initial]},
   Do[res = MatrixExp[-I*SparseArray[ArrayRules[mat]/.t->i,Dimensions[mat]],res], {i, ti, tf, dt}];
   Return[squ[res]]];
```

`evol1` is the straightforward method that computes the matrix product of all matrix exponentials and then applies it to the initial vector. `evol2` makes use of `MatrixExp[matrix,vector]`. Comparing speed and results:

```
res1 = evol1[mat, init, 0.01, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.634993, Null} *)
res2 = evol2[mat, init, 0.01, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.302688, Null} *)
Chop[res1 - res2] == ConstantArray[0, {36, 36}]
(* True *)
```

I feel like the `Do` in `evol2` is all but efficient but I do not get any idea about how to replace it. Is there any possibility to increase speed - not caring about memory usage?

**Edit** I am sorry for the initial confusion arising from a copy-paste error that affected the results.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Can you explain what the `t->3` does in `evol1` and `evol2`?

Comment: @sebhofer That is a good point. Copy-paste error when I changed something. Sorry for that

Comment: Just copy-pasting your code gives me `1/0.` and `(0.+0.I)ComplexInfinity` errors when calculating `res2`...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer That was due to the changes I made after copy-pasting (initial time caused singularity). See the updated question now

Comment: I also get the same error message as @MariusLadegårdMeyer and `res2` is nonsense. Please check you code again.

Comment: @sebhofer I have just copied the code from here to a notebook with fresh kernel and all runs without any errors. Did you possibly not refresh the page? My last update is ~50mins ago. Since then, everything should definitely run and also with the totally correct definitons - sorry for the error in the beginning. Please note that the initial time is `0.01` and no longer `0`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the new initial condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me first start with a cleaned up version of your `evol2`:

```
Clear@evol3
evol3[mat_, initial_, ti_, tf_] := 
  Module[{dt = (tf - ti)/10, res = col[initial]}, 
   Do[res = MatrixExp[-I*mat, res], {t, ti, tf, dt}];
   squ[res]];
```

Note that you don't need the complicated way to substitute numerical values for `t`, as `Do` uses `Block` internally which does this for you. (This results in a speedup of factor ~2 for me.) Also, you don't need `Return` here. Otherwise this is a straightforward and perfectly fine way to implement this. Note that one of the bottlenecks of `evol1` is almost certainly the prepending of new results to the list.

As Marius already pointed out, `Fold` is a functional alternative to the `Do` loop. My stab at it looks like this:

```
Clear@evol4
evol4[mat_, initial_, ti_, tf_] := 
  Module[{dt = (tf - ti)/10, init = col[initial], func},
   func[res_, s_] := Block[{t = s}, MatrixExp[-I*mat, res]];
   squ@Fold[func, init, Range[ti, tf, dt]]];
```

Note that there are many different (and maybe nicer) ways to define `func`, but I don't want to complicate things any more right now. Speedwise `evol3` and `evol4` are very similar. I'm pretty sure there are faster ways to compute this.

Comment: @Lukas Btw, have you tried computing the integral in the exponent instead of doing a Trotter decomposition?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Especially the internal usage of `Block` inside a `Do` was new to me. I guess, your question is if I have tried computing $e^{\int\limits_0^T S(t) dt}$? If so, no I haven't since $S(t_1)S(t_2)\neq S(t_2)S(t_1)$. This breaks down time-ordering so that there is no fully analytic form of the solution. If that's not what you were after: sorry I didn't get it

Comment: @Lukas Right! Sorry, I wasn't thinking straight there. That was what I meant.

Comment: @Lukas Another thing: the `Block` inside `Module` is not really important here, I just needed a way to define `func`. One other way is `SetDelayed @@ {func1[res_, t_], MatrixExp[-I*mat, res]}` (which, funnily, turns out to be a little slower).

Comment: I'm not so sure we can do much better than this actually. `evol3` now runs in 0.07 seconds on my machine, and scales perfectly linearly with the number of steps as expected. Since OP wanted 10^3-ish steps, I tried it and it takes less than five seconds.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yes, this looks most promising, indeed. However, I am struggling to get it working for my actual problem since the construction of matrices and passing them around between multiple functions is little bit different than here. But I am sure this will be done in less than an hour :)

Comment: @sebhofer Many thanks for your answer! Now that I managed to adapt into my code, I can solve the system extremely fast (Speedup of about 100-500 for my ODEs)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is certainly faster than using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve), but I think there is a mistake in the implementation, and the accuracy leaves much to be desired. Your ODE is:

$$m'(t) = -i S(t) . m(t)$$

This ODE can be discretized as follows:

$$m'(t) \Delta t \approx m(t + \Delta t) - m(t) \
\approx - i S(t) . m(t) \Delta t$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$m(t + \Delta t)\approx m(t)-i S(t) \Delta t\, .m(t)$$

or

$$m(t+\Delta t)\approx (I-i S(t) \Delta t) \, .m(t)$$

Here $I$ is the identity matrix. Using the exponential to approximate the RHS, we obtain:

$$m(t+\Delta t)\approx e^{-i S(t) \Delta t}.m(t)$$

which differs from yours with the presence of $\Delta t$ in the exponent. I will rewrite your `evol2` function to include this $\Delta t$ term, and to make it a function argument (instead of always using $(t_f-t_i)/10$). Also, I won't bother reshaping the vector into a matrix:

```
evol[mat_, initial_, {t_, ti_, tf_, dt_}] := Module[{res=col[initial]},
    Do[res = MatrixExp[-I mat dt, res], {t, ti, tf, dt}];
    res
]
```

Now, let's solve your ODE using [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
res = NDSolveValue[{m'[t] == -I mat . m[t], m[0] == col[init]}, m, {t, 0, 10}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.126, Null}

Let's compare the two approaches at time $t=1$:

```
discrete1 = evol[mat, init, {t, 0, 1, .1}]; //AbsoluteTiming
discrete2 = evol[mat, init, {t, 0, 1, .01}]; //AbsoluteTiming
discrete3 = evol[mat, init, {t, 0, 1, .001}]; //AbsoluteTiming
MinMax @ ReIm[res[1] - discrete1]
MinMax @ ReIm[res[1] - discrete2]
MinMax @ ReIm[res[1] - discrete3]
```

> {0.042896, Null}
>
> {0.336994, Null}
>
> {3.2513, Null}
>
> {-0.0549661, 0.11708}
>
> {-0.00586709, 0.0119637}
>
> {-0.000589242, 0.00119601}

As expected, the discrete approach timing increases linearly with the number of steps, and the accuracy also increases linearly. However, even with a $\Delta t$ of .001 the error is rather large. The situation is much worse at time $t=10$:

```
discrete1 = evol[mat, init, {t, 0, 10, .1}]; //AbsoluteTiming
discrete2 = evol[mat, init, {t, 0, 10, .01}]; //AbsoluteTiming
discrete3 = evol[mat, init, {t, 0, 10, .001}]; //AbsoluteTiming
MinMax @ ReIm[res[10] - discrete1]
MinMax @ ReIm[res[10] - discrete2]
MinMax @ ReIm[res[10] - discrete3]
```

> {0.347939, Null}
>
> {3.38722, Null}
>
> {34.2144, Null}
>
> {-0.273781, 0.294955}
>
> {-0.0395226, 0.0314886}
>
> {-0.00394035, 0.0032858}

I think it's much better to just use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) and rely on the error control that is built-in to the function.

*Timing update*

I forgot to mention that my version of `evol` is essentially the same as @sebhofer's *(my previous edit erroneously asserted that `evol` was faster)*:

```
r1 = squ @ evol[mat, init, {t, 0, 10, 1}]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = evol2[mat,init, 0, 10]; //RepeatedTiming
r3 = evol3[mat, init, 0, 10]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.037, Null}
>
> {0.16, Null}
>
> {0.038, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the error and a nice comparison of the error. You're absolutely right about rather using NDSolve, but since it can take really long for certain cases I do prefer the discretized version at least as a sanity check before going into deeper analysis that has to be less error affected

Answer (score 1):

Let me at least show you how to avoid the `Do` loop while I think about other possible improvements.

The idiomatic way is to use `Fold`. Here is my version:

```
evol3[mat_, initial_, ti_, tf_] := 
  Module[{dt = (tf - ti)/10, res = col[initial], 
    ar = ArrayRules[mat]},
  squ[Fold[
  MatrixExp[-I*SparseArray[ar /. t -> #2, Dimensions[mat]], #1] &, 
  res, Range[ti, tf, dt]]]
];
```

Notice that I don't compute the `ArrayRules` every time, since it can be done once. But this still only gives a minor improvement over your `evol2`, from 0.23 to 0.21 on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards `Fold`. I am looking forward to potential other improvements!

Comment: In fact, for my actual scenario it gave me a speedup of ~3 to compute the array rules only once! Awesome, although it had very little effect for this toy example